# Error "C compiler cannot create executables" happends when I install R-3.3.1 in linux system

Tags: r, linux, installation

I install `R-3.3.1` in linux system. I have installed all the needed dependency libraries before I install R. when I do the step:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/yccai/Programs/R 
--enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/lib" CPPFLAGS="-l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/include
```

an error `"C compiler cannot create executables"` occurs.

[image]

I have looked up the solutions on the internet. But it does not work.

The following is the file config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by R configure 3.3.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/home/yccai/Programs/R --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS=-L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/lib CPPFLAGS=-l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/include

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = console
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.18-308.el5
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Tue Feb 21 20:06:06 EST 2012

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/Anaconda2/bin
PATH: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
PATH: /usr/kerberos/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/netinfer
PATH: /home/applic/schrodinger2016
PATH: /home/applic/schrodinger2016/utilities
PATH: /home/applic/goldsuite-5.2/bin
PATH: /home/applic/goldsuite-5.2/GOLD/utilities
PATH: /home/applic/autodock4
PATH: /home/applic/autodock4/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/Bioclipse.2.6-final
PATH: /home/applic/dock6/bin
PATH: /home/applic/chimera/bin
PATH: /home/applic/dms
PATH: /gdata/lun1/software/g03/bsd
PATH: /gdata/lun1/software/g03/private
PATH: /gdata/lun1/software/g03
PATH: /home/rwshi/soft/g03
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/moe/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/vmd-1.9.2/bin
PATH: /home/rwshi/soft/openmpi/bin
PATH: /home/rwshi/soft/auto/autoconf/bin
PATH: /home/rwshi/soft/openmpi/include
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/simul/g_mmpbsa/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/simul/apbs/bin
PATH: /home/rwshi/soft/test/plumed/bin
PATH: /home/rwshi/soft/gmx465-1/bin
PATH: /home/applic/grace/bin
PATH: /home/lsun/Program/GASTON/gaston-1.1
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/simul/Brimm/bin
PATH: /home/applic/libsvm-3.20
PATH: /home/applic/libsvm-3.20/tools
PATH: /home/applic/MATLAB/R2012b/bin
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/propka-3.1
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/SmallApplic/IsoMIF
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/SmallApplic/catdcd4.0
PATH: /home/yccai/Programs/SmallApplic
PATH: /home/yccai/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3562: checking build system type
configure:3576: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3596: checking host system type
configure:3609: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:4307: checking for pwd
configure:4325: found /bin/pwd
configure:4338: result: /bin/pwd
configure:4346: checking whether builddir is srcdir
configure:4354: result: yes
configure:4359: checking for working aclocal
configure:4363: result: found
configure:4372: checking for working autoconf
configure:4376: result: found
configure:4385: checking for working automake
configure:4389: result: found
configure:4398: checking for working autoheader
configure:4402: result: found
configure:4411: checking whether ln -s works
configure:4415: result: yes
configure:4426: checking for bison
configure:4442: found /usr/bin/bison
configure:4453: result: bison -y
configure:4469: checking for ar
configure:4485: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:4496: result: ar
configure:4524: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:4592: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:4627: checking for sed
configure:4646: found /bin/sed
configure:4658: result: /bin/sed
configure:4676: checking for which
configure:4694: found /usr/bin/which
configure:4706: result: /usr/bin/which
configure:4726: checking for less
configure:4744: found /usr/bin/less
configure:4756: result: /usr/bin/less
configure:4779: checking for gtar
configure:4797: found /bin/gtar
configure:4809: result: /bin/gtar
configure:4831: checking for tex
configure:4849: found /usr/bin/tex
configure:4861: result: /usr/bin/tex
configure:4876: checking for pdftex
configure:4894: found /usr/bin/pdftex
configure:4906: result: /usr/bin/pdftex
configure:4926: checking for pdflatex
configure:4944: found /usr/bin/pdflatex
configure:4956: result: /usr/bin/pdflatex
configure:4976: checking for makeindex
configure:4994: found /usr/bin/makeindex
configure:5006: result: /usr/bin/makeindex
configure:5021: checking for texi2any
configure:5054: result: no
configure:5143: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
configure:5154: checking for texi2dvi
configure:5187: result: no
configure:5204: checking for kpsewhich
configure:5222: found /usr/bin/kpsewhich
configure:5234: result: /usr/bin/kpsewhich
configure:5246: checking for latex inconsolata package
configure:5262: result: missing
configure:5265: WARNING: neither inconsolata.sty nor zi4.sty found: PDF vignettes and package manuals will not be rendered optimally
configure:5279: checking for unzip
configure:5297: found /usr/bin/unzip
configure:5309: result: /usr/bin/unzip
configure:5325: checking for zip
configure:5343: found /usr/bin/zip
configure:5355: result: /usr/bin/zip
configure:5371: checking for gzip
configure:5389: found /bin/gzip
configure:5401: result: /bin/gzip
configure:5417: checking for bzip2
configure:5435: found /usr/bin/bzip2
configure:5447: result: /usr/bin/bzip2
configure:5465: checking for firefox
configure:5483: found /usr/bin/firefox
configure:5495: result: /usr/bin/firefox
configure:5512: result: using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
configure:5522: checking for acroread
configure:5555: result: no
configure:5522: checking for acroread4
configure:5555: result: no
configure:5522: checking for xdg-open
configure:5555: result: no
configure:5522: checking for evince
configure:5540: found /usr/bin/evince
configure:5552: result: /usr/bin/evince
configure:5573: checking for notangle
configure:5604: result: false
configure:5615: checking for realpath
configure:5646: result: false
configure:5659: checking for pkg-config
configure:5678: found /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure:5690: result: /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure:5750: checking for gcc
configure:5766: found /usr/local/bin/gcc
configure:5777: result: gcc
configure:6006: checking for C compiler version
configure:6015: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:6026: $? = 0
configure:6015: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC) 
configure:6026: $? = 0
configure:6015: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:6026: $? = 1
configure:6015: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:6026: $? = 1
configure:6046: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:6068: gcc  -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/include -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/lib conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:6072: $? = 1
configure:6110: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "R"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "R"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "R 3.3.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bugs.r-project.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.r-project.org"
| #define PACKAGE "R"
| #define VERSION "3.3.1"
| #define R_PLATFORM "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
| #define R_CPU "x86_64"
| #define R_VENDOR "pc"
| #define R_OS "linux-gnu"
| #define Unix 1
| #define R_ARCH ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:6115: error: in `/home/yccai/SoftPkg/R-3.3.1':
configure:6117: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_BLAS_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_BLAS_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPICFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPICFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/include'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX1XFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX1XFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX1XPICFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX1XPICFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX1XSTD_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX1XSTD_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX1X_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX1X_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXPICFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXPICFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_DEFS_set=
ac_cv_env_DEFS_value=
ac_cv_env_DYLIB_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_DYLIB_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_DYLIB_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_DYLIB_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FCPICFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FCPICFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FC_set=
ac_cv_env_FC_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_FPICFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FPICFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_JAVA_HOME_set=
ac_cv_env_JAVA_HOME_value=
ac_cv_env_LAPACK_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LAPACK_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/lib'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBnn_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBnn_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_MAIN_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_MAKE_set=
ac_cv_env_MAKE_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJC_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJC_value=
ac_cv_env_PKGCONF_set=
ac_cv_env_PKGCONF_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=set
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=:/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib/pkgconfig
ac_cv_env_R_BATCHSAVE_set=
ac_cv_env_R_BATCHSAVE_value=
ac_cv_env_R_BROWSER_set=
ac_cv_env_R_BROWSER_value=
ac_cv_env_R_PAPERSIZE_set=
ac_cv_env_R_PAPERSIZE_value=
ac_cv_env_R_PDFVIEWER_set=
ac_cv_env_R_PDFVIEWER_value=
ac_cv_env_R_PRINTCMD_set=
ac_cv_env_R_PRINTCMD_value=
ac_cv_env_R_SHELL_set=
ac_cv_env_R_SHELL_value=
ac_cv_env_SAFE_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SAFE_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXX1XLD_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXX1XLD_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXXLD_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_CXXLD_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_FCLD_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_FCLD_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_SHLIB_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_TAR_set=
ac_cv_env_TAR_value=
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_TCLTK_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_set=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_r_arch_set=
ac_cv_env_r_arch_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_GETWD=/bin/pwd
ac_cv_path_KPSEWHICH=/usr/bin/kpsewhich
ac_cv_path_MAKEINDEX=/usr/bin/makeindex
ac_cv_path_NOTANGLE=false
ac_cv_path_PAGER=/usr/bin/less
ac_cv_path_PDFLATEX=/usr/bin/pdflatex
ac_cv_path_PDFTEX=/usr/bin/pdftex
ac_cv_path_PKGCONF=/usr/bin/pkg-config
ac_cv_path_REALPATH=false
ac_cv_path_R_BROWSER=/usr/bin/firefox
ac_cv_path_R_BZIPCMD=/usr/bin/bzip2
ac_cv_path_R_GZIPCMD=/bin/gzip
ac_cv_path_R_PDFVIEWER=/usr/bin/evince
ac_cv_path_R_UNZIPCMD=/usr/bin/unzip
ac_cv_path_R_ZIPCMD=/usr/bin/zip
ac_cv_path_SED=/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_TAR=/bin/gtar
ac_cv_path_TEX=/usr/bin/tex
ac_cv_path_WHICH=/usr/bin/which
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AR=ar
ac_cv_prog_YACC='bison -y'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='aclocal'
ALLOCA=''
AR='ar'
ARFLAGS='rc'
AUTOCONF='autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='automake'
AWK=''
BITMAP_CPPFLAGS=''
BITMAP_LIBS=''
BLAS_LIBS0=''
BLAS_LIBS=''
BLAS_SHLIB_FALSE=''
BLAS_SHLIB_TRUE=''
BUILDDIR_IS_SRCDIR='yes'
BUILD_AQUA_FALSE=''
BUILD_AQUA_TRUE=''
BUILD_CC=''
BUILD_DEVCAIRO_FALSE=''
BUILD_DEVCAIRO_TRUE=''
BUILD_HTML_FALSE=''
BUILD_HTML_TRUE='#'
BUILD_INCLUDED_LIBINTL=''
BUILD_LIBINTL_FALSE=''
BUILD_LIBINTL_TRUE=''
BUILD_LTO_FALSE=''
BUILD_LTO_TRUE='#'
BUILD_R=''
BUILD_TRE_FALSE=''
BUILD_TRE_TRUE=''
BUILD_TZONE_FALSE=''
BUILD_TZONE_TRUE=''
BUILD_X11_FALSE=''
BUILD_X11_TRUE=''
BUILD_XDR_FALSE=''
BUILD_XDR_TRUE=''
BYTE_COMPILE_PACKAGES_FALSE='#'
BYTE_COMPILE_PACKAGES_TRUE=''
CAIROX11_CPPFLAGS=''
CAIROX11_LIBS=''
CAIRO_CPPFLAGS=''
CAIRO_LIBS=''
CATOBJEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CFLAG_VISIBILITY=''
COMPILE_FORTRAN_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_FALSE=''
COMPILE_FORTRAN_DOUBLE_COMPLEX_TRUE=''
CPICFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/include'
CROSS_COMPILING_FALSE=''
CROSS_COMPILING_TRUE=''
CURL_CONFIG=''
CURL_CPPFLAGS=''
CURL_LIBS=''
CXX1X=''
CXX1XFLAGS=''
CXX1XPICFLAGS=''
CXX1XSTD=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP0=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXPICFLAGS=''
C_VISIBILITY=''
DATADIRNAME=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
DYLIB_EXT=''
DYLIB_LD=''
DYLIB_LDFLAGS=''
DYLIB_UNDEFINED_ALLOWED_FALSE=''
DYLIB_UNDEFINED_ALLOWED_TRUE=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F77=''
F77_VISIBILITY=''
FC=''
FCFLAGS=''
FCFLAGS_f90=''
FCFLAGS_f95=''
FCLIBS=''
FCPICFLAGS=''
FFLAGS=''
FGREP=''
FLIBS=''
FLIBS_IN_SO=''
FOUNDATION_CPPFLAGS=''
FOUNDATION_LIBS=''
FPICFLAGS=''
FW_VERSION=''
GENCAT=''
GETWD='/bin/pwd'
GLIBC21=''
GLIBC2=''
GREP=''
HAVE_ASPRINTF=''
HAVE_CXX11=''
HAVE_FORTRAN_DOUBLE_COMPLEX=''
HAVE_POSIX_PRINTF=''
HAVE_SNPRINTF=''
HAVE_VISIBILITY=''
HAVE_WPRINTF=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_INFO=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTOBJEXT=''
INTERNET_LIBS=''
INTLBISON=''
INTLLIBS=''
INTLOBJS=''
INTL_LIBTOOL_SUFFIX_PREFIX=''
INTL_MACOSX_LIBS=''
JAR=''
JAVA=''
JAVAC=''
JAVAH=''
JAVA_CPPFLAGS0=''
JAVA_HOME=''
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
JAVA_LIBS0=''
KPSEWHICH='/usr/bin/kpsewhich'
LAPACK_LDFLAGS=''
LAPACK_LIBS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/lib'
LIBICONV=''
LIBINTL=''
LIBM=''
LIBMULTITHREAD=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPTH=''
LIBPTH_PREFIX=''
LIBR0='-L$(R_HOME)/lib$(R_ARCH)'
LIBR1='-lR'
LIBR_LDFLAGS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTHREAD=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBTOOL_DEPS=''
LIBnn='lib64'
LIPO=''
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBICONV=''
LTLIBINTL=''
LTLIBMULTITHREAD=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LTLIBPTH=''
LTLIBTHREAD=''
LTO=''
LTOALL=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAIN_CFLAGS=''
MAIN_FFLAGS=''
MAIN_LD=''
MAIN_LDFLAGS=''
MAJ_MIN_VERSION='3.3'
MAKE='make'
MAKEINDEX='/usr/bin/makeindex'
MAKEINFO=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
NOTANGLE='false'
OBJC=''
OBJCFLAGS=''
OBJCXX=''
OBJCXXFLAGS=''
OBJC_LIBS=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OPENMP_CFLAGS=''
OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=''
OPENMP_FCFLAGS=''
OPENMP_FFLAGS=''
OSF_SH_BUG=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='R'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='https://bugs.r-project.org'
PACKAGE_NAME='R'
PACKAGE_STRING='R 3.3.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='R'
PACKAGE_URL='https://www.r-project.org'
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.3.1'
PAGER='/usr/bin/less'
PAPERCONF=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PDFLATEX='/usr/bin/pdflatex'
PDFTEX='/usr/bin/pdftex'
PKGCONF='/usr/bin/pkg-config'
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=':/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib/pkgconfig'
POSUB=''
PRI_MACROS_BROKEN=''
RANLIB=''
RBLAS_LDFLAGS=''
READLINE_LIBS=''
REALPATH='false'
RLAPACK_LDFLAGS=''
RMATH_HAVE_EXPM1=''
RMATH_HAVE_HYPOT=''
RMATH_HAVE_LOG1P=''
RMATH_HAVE_WORKING_LOG1P=''
R_ARCH=''
R_BATCHSAVE=''
R_BROWSER='/usr/bin/firefox'
R_BZIPCMD='/usr/bin/bzip2'
R_CONFIG_ARGS=' '\''--prefix=/home/yccai/Programs/R'\'' '\''--enable-R-shlib'\'' '\''LDFLAGS=-L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/lib'\'' '\''CPPFLAGS=-l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/include'\'' '\''PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib/pkgconfig'\'' '\''CFLAGS='\'' '\''LIBS='\'''
R_DEFS=''
R_DYLIB_EXT=''
R_GZIPCMD='/bin/gzip'
R_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
R_OPENMP_CFLAGS=''
R_OPENMP_FFLAGS=''
R_OS='linux-gnu'
R_OSTYPE='unix'
R_PAPERSIZE=''
R_PDFVIEWER='/usr/bin/evince'
R_PLATFORM='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
R_PRINTCMD=''
R_PROFILING=''
R_RD4PDF='times,hyper'
R_SHELL=''
R_SYSTEM_ABI=''
R_UNZIPCMD='/usr/bin/unzip'
R_XTRA_CFLAGS=''
R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS2='-I$(R_INCLUDE_DIR)'
R_XTRA_CPPFLAGS=''
R_XTRA_CXXFLAGS=''
R_XTRA_FFLAGS=''
R_XTRA_LIBS=''
R_ZIPCMD='/usr/bin/zip'
Rshlibpath_var=''
SAFE_FFLAGS=''
SED='/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIB_CFLAGS=''
SHLIB_CXX1XLD=''
SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS=''
SHLIB_CXXFLAGS=''
SHLIB_CXXLD=''
SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS=''
SHLIB_EXT=''
SHLIB_FCLD=''
SHLIB_FCLDFLAGS=''
SHLIB_FFLAGS=''
SHLIB_LD=''
SHLIB_LDFLAGS=''
SHLIB_LIBADD=''
SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS=''
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS=''
SHLIB_OPENMP_FCFLAGS=''
SHLIB_OPENMP_FFLAGS=''
STATICR1=''
STATICR2=''
STRIP=''
TAR='/bin/gtar'
TCLTK_CPPFLAGS=''
TCLTK_LIBS=''
TCL_CONFIG=''
TEX='/usr/bin/tex'
TEXI2DVI=''
TEXI2DVICMD='texi2dvi'
TIRPC_CPPFLAGS=''
TK_CONFIG=''
USE_EXPORTFILES_FALSE=''
USE_EXPORTFILES_TRUE=''
USE_EXTERNAL_BLAS_FALSE=''
USE_EXTERNAL_BLAS_TRUE=''
USE_EXTERNAL_LAPACK_FALSE=''
USE_EXTERNAL_LAPACK_TRUE=''
USE_ICU=''
USE_ICU_APPLE=''
USE_INCLUDED_LIBINTL=''
USE_MMAP_ZLIB_FALSE=''
USE_MMAP_ZLIB_TRUE=''
USE_NLS=''
USE_NLS_FALSE=''
USE_NLS_TRUE=''
USE_RECOMMENDED_PACKAGES_FALSE=''
USE_RECOMMENDED_PACKAGES_TRUE=''
USE_VECLIB_G95FIX_FALSE=''
USE_VECLIB_G95FIX_TRUE=''
VERSION='3.3.1'
WANT_JAVA_FALSE='#'
WANT_JAVA_TRUE=''
WANT_R_FRAMEWORK_FALSE=''
WANT_R_FRAMEWORK_TRUE='#'
WANT_R_SHLIB_FALSE='#'
WANT_R_SHLIB_TRUE=''
WANT_R_STATIC_FALSE=''
WANT_R_STATIC_TRUE='#'
WHICH='/usr/bin/which'
WOE32DLL=''
XMKMF=''
XTRA_INTL_CPPFLAGS=''
X_CFLAGS=''
X_EXTRA_LIBS=''
X_LIBS=''
X_PRE_LIBS=''
YACC='bison -y'
YFLAGS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_ct_F77=''
ac_ct_FC=''
ac_ct_OBJC=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
config_opts=' '\''--prefix=/home/yccai/Programs/R'\'' '\''--enable-R-shlib'\'' '\''LDFLAGS=-L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/lib -L/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/lib'\'' '\''CPPFLAGS=-l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/bzip2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/xz-5.2.2/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/pcre-8.39/include -l/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/curl-7.50.3/include'\'' '\''PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/home/yccai/Programs/Libs/zlib/lib/pkgconfig'\'' '\''CFLAGS='\'' '\''LIBS='\'''
custom_JAVA_CPPFLAGS=''
custom_JAVA_HOME=''
custom_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''
custom_JAVA_LIBS=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/${LIBnn}'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/yccai/Programs/R'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
r_arch=''
rdocdir='${rhome}/doc'
rincludedir='${rhome}/include'
rsharedir='${rhome}/share'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
shlibpath_var=''
striplib=''
stripstaticlib=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
use_tcltk=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

r_cc_lo_rules_frag=''
r_cc_rules_frag=''
r_cxx_rules_frag=''
r_objc_rules_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "R"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "R"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.3.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "R 3.3.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "https://bugs.r-project.org"
#define PACKAGE_URL "https://www.r-project.org"
#define PACKAGE "R"
#define VERSION "3.3.1"
#define R_PLATFORM "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
#define R_CPU "x86_64"
#define R_VENDOR "pc"
#define R_OS "linux-gnu"
#define Unix 1
#define R_ARCH ""

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: I have successfully installed R from source file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639138/configure-error-installing-r-3-3-2-on-ubuntu-checking-whether-bzip2-support-suf

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully pass the header file to the installer with `$CPATH` variable

```
export CPATH=/panfs/home/yangpc/soft/lib/zlib-1.2.8/include/:$CPATH
./configure --prefix=/panfs/home/yangpc/soft/R/R_soft/ --enable-R-shlib  --with-libpth-prefix=/panfs/home/yangpc/soft/
```