# configure error installing R-3.3.2 on Ubuntu: checking whether bzip2 support suffices... configure: error: bzip2 library and headers are required

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, configure

Trying to install R-3.3.2 but when I use `$./configure`, I keep getting the error:

`checking whether bzip2 support suffices... configure: error: bzip2 library and headers are required`

Comment: I have bzip2 installed: `$ bzip2` then `bzip2: I won't write compressed data to a terminal` `bzip2: For help, type: "bzip2 --help"`

Comment: I have encountered the same problem, hope you can post the solution here when you solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @pengchy I had the same problem with `zlib`, I found out that, strangely, the source code's `configure` script checks the version numbers by `strcmp`. My installed zlib version was "1.2.11", and the minimum requirement is "1.2.6" which is lexicographically smaller. I changed that line and it worked.

Comment: @pengchy I explained it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076936/zlib-bz2-library-and-headers-are-requried-for-compiling-r)

Comment: @cartoonist thank you, I have successfully [installed R-3.3.2 from the source file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639138/configure-error-installing-r-3-3-2-on-ubuntu-checking-whether-bzip2-support-suf/41362423#41362423)

Comment: Installing the latest developmental version of bz2, `apt-get install libbz2-dev` as of 02/14/17 solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 18):

It worked for me after:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Comment: yum install bzip2-devel for RHEL OS

Answer (score 5):

I have successfully compiled R from source, the following steps need special attention:

1. install dependent libraries:
   zlib-1.2.8, bzip2-1.0.6, xz-5.2.2, pcre-8.39, curl-7.52.1.
   Specifically, to compile bzip2, The Makefile should be modified:
   original: CC=gcc
   after modification: CC=gcc -fPIC
2. pass the library and header file to the configure with proper variables:

   export CPATH=/opt/zlib-1.2.8/include/:/opt/bzip2-1.0.6/include/:/opt/xz-5.2.2/include/:/opt/pcre-8.39/include/

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/zlib-1.2.8/lib/:/opt/bzip2-1.0.6/lib/:/opt/xz-5.2.2/lib/:/opt/pcre-8.39/lib/

   ./configure --prefix=/opt/R/R_soft/ --enable-R-shlib  --with-libpth-prefix=/opt/ CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/bzip2-1.0.6/include/ -I/opt/zlib-1.2.8/include/ -I/opt/xz-5.2.2/include/ -I/opt/pcre-8.39/include/ -I/opt/curl-7.52.1/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/xz-5.2.2/lib/ -L/opt/zlib-1.2.8/lib/ -L/opt/bzip2-1.0.6/lib/ -L/opt/pcre-8.39/lib/ -L/opt/curl-7.52.1/lib/"

It seems `CPATH` and `CPPFLAGS` is redundant here, I found the `CPPFLAGS` AND `LDFLAGS` not worked.

Answer (score 1):

First off, are you aware that you can get [prebuilt binaries of *current* R](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) ?

Second, your comment on the `bzip2` *binary* has no bearing on the need for the *library* R needs to compile and link against.

Third, you can search:  `apt-cache search bzip2 | grep library` would have gotten you there.

Fourth, for all existing packages you can actually install their *known* build dependencies.  But see point one, you probably do not want to build from source.

Fifth, and closing:  `sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev` answers your (narrow) question but you will likely have further issues. There is [an entire manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html) devoted to installing and administering R which has all the answers for you.

Comment: The error indeed exist. Because I want to install R into my own directory on the Linux server, so the bzip2 source file is compiled before installing R 3.3.2. However, the "checking if bzip2 version >= 1.0.6... no" error still exist although the version bzip2 indeed 1.0.6.

Comment: I can't understand the prebuilt installation instructions. It says to add the code to '/etc/apt/sources.list' but I have no idea what this is. What happened to downloading and installing tars...

Comment: Nobody is taking source downloads away from me. We "merely" prebuilt binaries created and customized by people familiar with the source package at hand.  I, and a lot of ther people, find that preferable.  As for `/etc/apt/sources.list`, try one of the many basic tutorials for Debian or Ubuntu package management.  HTH.