# zlib/bz2 library and headers are requried for compiling R

Tags: r, compilation, configure

Trying to compile R-3.3.2 on Debian Jessie, all dependencies are installed. However the `./configure` script complains about the `zlib`/`bzip2` library versions not matching with the minimum requirement.

Minimum version required:

- `zlib`: 1.2.6 (installed version: **1.2.11**)
- `bzip2`: 1.0.6 (installed version: **1.0.6**)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the parts of `configure` script checking the library versions, it seems that it compares versions with `strcmp` or `strncmp`. Since "1.2.11" is lexicographically smaller that "1.2.6" it return a non-zero value indicating that the match failed. Besides, it just compares the first 5 characters which is also not what it is intented. So, it's a bug in configure script. Changing the script fixed the issue.

For zlib, find this line:

```
exit(strncmp(ZLIB_VERSION, "1.2.5", 5) < 0);
```

Change it to:

```
exit(ZLIB_VERNUM < 0x1250);
```

Comment: See also: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2017-January/444162.html

Comment: @HaozheXie I think, it should be a bug report rather than an answer in SO.

Comment: This is already commented out and I am still getting the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues installing R myself, specifically with the error

```
checking for BZ2_bzlibVersion in -lbz2... no
```

I had to install `libbz2-dev` to get that error to go away.

Unfortunately, I came across a few more issues while running `./configure` and had to do a little more digging to find out how to solve it.

[Discussion on issue](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/PCRE-and-setting-C-LD-and-CPP-FLAGS-for-a-local-r-devel-installation-td4705648.htmlhttp://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/PCRE-and-setting-C-LD-and-CPP-FLAGS-for-a-local-r-devel-installation-td4705648.html)

After reading that, I had realized I had to install a couple packages like `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, `libpcre3`, and `liblzma-dev` to finally finish the configuration.

The cited link suggested

> At this stage you could have as well tried to install R 3.2.0RC ... 
>   R-devel has not yet diverged much.

Personally, I think that installing an older version to resolve dependency issues reeks of laziness, but that's just my two cents.